# Delete previous recipients in Messages

Tags: macos, messages

I am running Messages on Mavericks. When I begin to type someone I wish to chat with, I get a list of suggestions. I wish to remove some people from that list. I have removed them from my Contacts already, but they persist in the list.

I know that Mac Mail has a way to edit the list of previous recipients. Does Messages provide the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you still have 'active' Messages with those deleted contacts?

Comment: Like Andrew U. Said. There's probably a conversation between the two of you somewhere in the list of conversations. Try and search for it/them if it's a really big list.